# how to fix errors like this "DiscordAPIError: Missing Access"

Tags: node.js, discord

I followed the tutorial from youtube and I found an error like this and I don't know where the problem is. When i run `node my_bot.js`, Then there is an error `DiscordAPIError: Missing Access`.

I've tried a few things. My expectation will appear the words Hello World on discord. The result is an error.

I think, there is nothing wrong with my code

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Connected as " + client.user.tag)

    client.user.setActivity('you', { type: 'WATCHING' });

    client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
        console.log(guild.name);
            guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
                console.log(` - ${channel.name} ${channel.type} ${channel.id}`)
            })
            // General channel id: 956453625889185826
    })

    let generalChannel = client.channels.cache.get("956453625889185826")
    generalChannel.send("Hello World")
})

client.login("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

Result:

```
Connected as Davd#3016
gavbot
 - Text Channels GUILD_CATEGORY 956453625889185824
 - Voice Channels GUILD_CATEGORY 956453625889185825
 - general GUILD_TEXT 956453625889185826
 - General GUILD_VOICE 956453625889185827
C:\Users\User\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\User\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\User\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\User\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/956453625889185826/messages',
  code: 50001,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: 'Hello World',
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, `Missing access` means that your bot doesn't have the permissions to send a message in the channel.
Make sure your bot has the `Send message` permission in the channel you want to send the message